# microsoft login fails with passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I use this code

```
const passport = require('passport')
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy
const config = require('@arades/devonso-core/config')

passport.use('azuread-openidconnect', new OAuth2Strategy({
authorizationURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize',
tokenURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token',
clientID: config.xrm.clientId,
clientSecret: config.xrm.clientSecret,
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8081/auth/microsoft/redirect'
},
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  // Store user information in session or database
  return done(null, profile)
}
))

module.exports = passport
```

to use microsoft login in my app. but when i send a request lo login route, i get status code 200 with this message:

> Something went wrong and we can't sign you in right now. Please try again later.

How should i find the problem?